# How to make POST API call with authentication header from watch app?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos

I want to make a POST API call with authentication header from watch app to fetch some data. Since, all the bearer tokens & user ID are encoded and saved in iPhone after login, how can I have access to those datas from Watch app? Is there any ***secure*** mechanism to get it or it's just a normal message transfer via ***applicationContext***.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where are bearer tokens and user ID saved (example: Keychain, CoreData, Disk etc)? If you know where, then you can retrieve it from there.

Comment: @user1046037, It's saved using NSCoding in iPhone. Now, how can I access that data for Watch in Watch Extension?

Comment: NSCoding is a coder, after that what do they do, dig more into the code see where it gets saved